# Text alignment in moderncv

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, moderncv

I am making my cv with moderncv class. I have two questions:

1- How to align first and second column of "Programming Languages" vertically? So that, the text "Programming Languages" would be centered.

2- How to align "Good"s in Programming Languages and "Company" in Certificates horizontally?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Computer skills}
\cvitem{Programming Language} {
C \quad Good\newline
C+ \quad Good\newline
C++ \quad Good}

\section{Certificates}
\cvitem{Date}{A certificate \quad Company}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you check the examples comming with class `moderncv` you can find several commands prepared doing a layout you want.

But if you insist some lines of your code be reworked.  But at last (in my opinion) your question to have a centered "Programming languages" breaks the layout principles of class `moderncv`.  The first column is right justified, so you can change the width of the first column without layout problems.

Please see my following MWE and please stude the shown commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Computer skills}
\cvitem{Programming Language}{
C   \hfill Good\newline
C+  \hfill Good\newline
C++ \hfill Good}

\subsection{Programming Language}
\cvdoubleitem{Good}{C, C+, C++}{basic}{Pascal, FORTRAN, COBOL}

\subsection{Programming Language}
\cvitemwithcomment{C}{Good}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{C+}{Good}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{C++}{Good}{Comment}

\section{Certificates}
\cvitemwithcomment{Date}{A certificate}{Company}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of my mwe]